# in mongoDB i want to update an object depending upon object's other elements value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection in MongoDB.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aaf51369d8bdfe288d1cb71"),
    "companyName" : "ABC",
    "name" : "BCD",
    "buildInfo" : [ 
        {
            "Branch" : "IT",
            "Subjects" : [ 
                "Math", 
                "English", 
                "Computer", 
            ]
        }
    ],
    "currentDate" : ISODate("2018-03-14T14:09:24.374Z"),
    "lastModifiedBy" : "ABC.com"
}
```

I want to insert a new object into "buildInfo" if that branch won't be there. If the branch exists I want to update "Subjects".

I am passing Branch and Subjects to this method.

```
myDb.collection('ABCDEF').findAndModify( 
        {'name':'BCD', 'companyName': 'ABC'},
        [['_id','asc']],
        {
            $addToSet: {
                'buildInfo.$[i].Subjects': Subjects
            }
        },
        {  upsert: true, arrayFilters: [{ 'i.Branch': Branch }] }
```

But it's updating if the branch is there, but it's not creating a new object if a branch is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Upsert works on document level only, not for embedded documents.

The simplest way is to issue 3 consecutive updates:

```
myDb.collection('ABCDEF').findAndModify( 
    {'name':'BCD', 'companyName': 'ABC', '$or': [{'buildInfo':{'$exists': false}}, {'buildInfo': {'$not':{ '$type': 'array' }}}]},
    [['_id','asc']],
    {
        $set: { 'buildInfo': [] }
    },
    {  upsert: true}
)
```

followed by

```
myDb.collection('ABCDEF').findAndModify( 
    {'name':'BCD', 'companyName': 'ABC', 'buildInfo.Branch': {$nin: [Branch]}},
    [['_id','asc']],
    {
        $push: {
            { buildInfo: { Branch: Branch, Subjects: [] } }
        }
    }
)
```

followed by

```
myDb.collection('ABCDEF').findAndModify( 
    {'name':'BCD', 'companyName': 'ABC', 'buildInfo.Branch': Branch},
    [['_id','asc']],
    {
        $addToSet: {
            'buildInfo.$[].Subjects': Subject
        }
    }
)
```

The first one adds empty `buildInfo` array to documents that does not have one. The second update adds a subdocument with specific `Branch` and empty `Subjects` to documents that don't have the branch. The last query adds `Subject` to the set.

Comment: Its giving below error
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: The field 'buildInfo' must be an array

Comment: what is the logic you are applying here, can you explain?

Comment: The error says there are documents without `buildInfo` at all. I have updated the answer